# WMS Authentication in VB6

Tags: authentication, vb6, wms

I am trying to modify a function that was previously built that uses a WMS request and returns layer information using an xmlHTTP request.

However, we now have a WMS server that has a username and password.

Any ideas on how to use these credentials. Is is something in the request string, or does the xmlHTTP request have to be authorized.

Thanks?!?!

Answer (score 0):

Looking on [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=WMS+authentication&meta=) reveals a few types of WMS authentication.
You'll need to finsout what method your WMS uses.
If it supports standard HTTP auth then you just need to parse out the auth details and either add the appropriate `Authorization` header.
Note that WinInet supports URL based authentication details but other clinets may not. You'll need to provide more information on the client library in use before we can give more details.